# Unsure on implementation of an AJAX idea

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I was thinking about how to make an instant messaging application, and wanted to not have to send an AJAX request so often (one every .2s), and I came across the following idea:

1. Send an AJAX request from the user side, to the server.
2. Only respond once there is a change in the MySQL database
3. And then send the next AJAX request once the response has been recorded and parsed

I'm aware of how to do the first and third steps, but the second one is going over my head.

*I'm assuming that for step 2, I'll need to store the request somewhere, while the PHP script is continuously looping and looking for some changes, and once there is a change, the saved request would be responded to.*

**EDIT**
Didn't know about WebSockets, should've used those.

Comment: You could use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with the setting `ON UPDATE` to a row in your database table and check by that. You can apply these settings automatically in your settings.

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to constantly loop through in my PHP file, while having recorded the request in some location until the file can respond to it?

Comment: Do not re-invent the wheel. Read on long polling and websockets.

Comment: With php you do not want to do long polling, because this won't scale well with php.

Comment: @t.niese That's true but it also depends on the webserver used. I just stated how these technologies are called so he can do his research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion and query the database every 2 seconds, until you find new data to be served to the user. So basically you could do something like

```
public function isDataUpdated($lastId) {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`message_id` > $lastId";
   return (bool)(count($this->executeSQL($query)) > 0);
}

public function fetchNewMessages () {
    if ($this->isDataUpdated($_GET['last_id'])) {
        /* We have new data! Send it to the user */
    } else {
        sleep(2); // wait for 2 seconds
        $this->fetchNewMessages(); // we use recursion to query the database every 2 seconds to find new data
    }
}
```

Although, it is not the best of solutions, it would hopefully work. I would recommend taking a look at [Sockets in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) to better achieve what you want

Comment: I wasn't aware of websockets and the like until now, I appreciate you mentioning them.

Comment: @Fate using php you will have one process running per request, and the number of processes is limited to a certain number, how many depends on the server configuration. Because of that, you want to keep the time the script runs as short as possible. If the limit is e.g. `10` and you have 10 users on your system, and an additional one will come to the server then this user will get an error message the request timed out.